# unexpected memory usage in linux kernel version 4.14

Tags: linux, memory-management, out-of-memory, embedded-linux, u-boot

in my embedded linux with kernel 4.14 I have about 90MB free memory. when I transfer a file with size of 20MB to my linux with `scp` command(or specially with drag and drop a file with MoboXterm software) from another computer, the free memory decrease until it reaches 1MB free !
in output of `free` command I see that these decreased memory added to buff/cache! and if I drop cache manually it frees only (about) 3MB! This problem has caused my application to run out of memory.

I stop my services and applications and try again but this problem not resolved! when I change my kernel to 4.19 , for transferring a file with 10Mb size, the free memory decreased only 10Mb and added to buff/cache and it released after some minutes or when it needed. u-boot is my bootloader and my bootargs is : `bootargs=root=/dev/mtdblock1 rootfstype=jffs2 rw console=ttyS0,115200 ramdisk_size=90000`

Why the Linux kernel(in 4.14 version) does not automatically empty the buff/cache memory when other Apps needded? I have no memory leakage in my application.

Comment: Hmmm, 90MB free and `ramdisk_size=90000` - you're not copying the file to the ramdisk, are you?

Comment: I copy file to a partition of NAND flash. not Ram .

Comment: Have you run `sync` after `scp` is done?

Comment: I test it nd no changes . this problem occur when I drag and drop a file to my embedded system in MoboXterm software